# TypeScript - creating child class instance inside parent class

Tags: typescript, class, inheritance, typescript-generics

Please take a look at the following example:

```
type Task = (input: number) => number;

abstract class ParentClass {
    constructor(protected tasks: Task[] = []) {}

    protected abstract getDescendantClass<T extends this>(): new (tasks: Task[]) => T;

    protected addTask(task: Task) {
        const DecendantClass = this.getDescendantClass();
        return new DecendantClass([...this.tasks, task]);
    }

    exec(value: number) {
        for (const task of this.tasks) {
            value = task(value);
        }
        return value;
    }
}

abstract class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    add(toAdd: number) {
        return this.addTask((v) => v + toAdd);
    }
}

class FinalChildClass extends ChildClass {
    // ❌ TS error (1)
    protected getDescendantClass() {
        return FinalChildClass;
    }

    multiply(factor: number) {
        return this.addTask((v) => v * factor);
    }
}

const Tasker = new FinalChildClass();

// ✔️ No TS errors (2) - I'm able to chain functions from all children
const task = Tasker.add(2).multiply(2).add(2);
const result = task.exec(2);

console.log(result); // 10
```

I'm trying to create a class that is able to create instances of descendant
classes that it can't possibly know about.

I managed to implement it, and
type in a way that enables chaining API that I was after (2), however I got
stuck at this type script error (1):

```
'FinalChildClass' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T',
but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'FinalChildClass'.
```

How can I type it to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

There are some good reasons for that type error. For the way you happen to be using these features, your approach looks very reasonable. However, if we stretch the example a bit, I think you'll begin to see why it breaks down.

Let's create a new class named "FinalFinal" that extends "Final". Note that this is perfectly legal.

```
class FinalFinalChildClass extends FinalChildClass {
    divide(divisor: number) {
        return this.addTask((v) => v / divisor);
    }
}
```

Our new code will now be:

```
const Tasker = new FinalFinalChildClass();

// ✔️ No TS errors (2) - I'm able to chain functions from all children
const task = Tasker.add(2).multiply(2).add(2).divide(5);
const result = task.exec(2);

console.log(result); // 2
```

TypeScript is perfectly happy (except for the pesky error you've already noted), but at runtime our `getDescendantClass()` does not return a constructor which will build a new `FinalFinalChildClass` as promised. Instead, it will build a `FinalChildClass`. So even though TypeScript will compile, we will get the following runtime error:

```
Tasker.add(...).multiply(...).add(...).divide is not a function
```

This is because the error message was exactly correct: "*T **was** instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'FinalChildClass'*" and now our TypeScript types and the actual runtime prototype chain are out of whack.

[Try it for yourself.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKghgZwNZQLxQBRwE4HMBcAdgK4C2ARhNgJRoB8UJFVA3ALABQnc5Cw2cAMbAoggDaIEUAAo4IhYAGEJCKQG9OULaID2hPtmLCd2DGGw7gEYRAAmUYIiQJ8sJwG0AumihfaagF9OTW1zS2srex4DIRFcCGAAEQgEQXlbOAVlSQAeGCgIAA8rQlspYAALAEsEOgxqV0IIAHdMR2QXN2Q-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-RKc+3HHGIOi4Bg9mOTCIGgbRQA)

Instead, we need a more resilient approach which is able to build new instances of Descendant classes.

One approach is to abandon the misguided attempt to divine the descendant type from within the base class. We don't know, and can't know. Instead, we can lean on convention and use existing JavaScript APIs to get the constructor for the current `this`.

Our new approach has discarded the broken `getDescendantClass()` function and instead uses `Object.getPrototypeOf(this).constructor` to get the constructor. (Note that the returned type is `any`, so we need to use a little explicit typing to clue the compiler into the expected return type.)

```
abstract class ParentClass {
    constructor(protected tasks: Task[] = []) {}

    protected addTask(task: Task) {
        const ctor:new (tasks: Task[]) => this = Object.getPrototypeOf(this).constructor;
        return new ctor([...this.tasks, task]);
    }

    exec(value: number) {
        for (const task of this.tasks) {
            value = task(value);
        }
        return value;
    }
}

abstract class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    add(toAdd: number) {
        return this.addTask((v) => v + toAdd);
    }
}

class FinalChildClass extends ChildClass {
    multiply(factor: number) {
        return this.addTask((v) => v * factor);
    }
}

class FinalFinalChildClass extends FinalChildClass {
    divide(divisor: number) {
        return this.addTask((v) => v / divisor);
    }
}

const Tasker = new FinalFinalChildClass();

// ✔️ No TS errors (2) - I'm able to chain functions from all children
const task = Tasker.add(2).multiply(2).add(2).divide(5);
const result = task.exec(2);

console.log(result); // 2
```

This approach both gives us good strong typing at compile time:

[image]

And error free code at runtime:

[image]

Of course, there is still a risk that someone could come along and implement a class that extends `ParentClass` but implements an incompatible constructor. Unfortunately, I am not aware of any TypeScript feature which allows a class author to restrict the way in which subclasses are implemented. A certain degree of convention and documentation will be required, but that doesn't seem too unusual in our field.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very well written response : ) Using `getPrototypeOf` didn't feel very typescript-ish to me so I tried to avoid it, but now that you pointed out a flaw in my design, I'm starting to think, that it my be the only solution. I think the safety of this solution could be improved if I would modify `ParentClass` like this https://tsplay.dev/mxD4Km (so there is no need to worry about a proper construcor).

Comment: I have a feeling that there may be another solution that in your example would allow: `Tasker.divide (2).multiply(2)` but not `Tasker.divide (2).multiply(2).divide` (since at that point we're back to `FinalClass` from `FinalFinalClass`) so I'll leave this question open a bit longer, but if no one will suggest anything else, I'll definitly use your approach.

Comment: @GreenTea222 - I'm not clear on what you mean. Are you concerned that `.divide(2).multiply(2).divide(2)` will break? If so, then I believe my solution will work just fine as you are _always_ working with `FinalFinalClass`. Or do you mean that your _goal_ is for `.multiply(2).divide(2)` to break? In which case you are asking the `ParentClass` not only to divine the base class, but to also figure out where on the prototype chain `.multiply` exists. TypeScript can't do that for you, but you could probably figure it out by examining `getPrototypeOf()` yourself.

Comment: `const task = Tasker.add(2).multiply(2).add(2).divide(5).multiply(3).divide(2).add(7).multiply(2).divide(10);` returns the expected `2`

Comment: `Or do you mean that your goal is for .multiply(2).divide(2) to break?` Yes, I thought it could be an alternative solution that would be a bit more type safe when it comes to constructor.

Comment: @GreenTea222 - You are instantiating `FinalFinalChildClass`, so the constructor will always be for `FinalFinalChildClass`. If you want to return a constructor for a base class, then you can walk up the prototype chain for the current object, e.g. `Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(this)).constructor`. Note that you'll be essentially blind as to the what the base object is. It could be `FinalChildClass`, `ChildClass` or `ParentClass`, or something else entirely. You'll only know if you start examining static properties, at which point you've lost most of the value of inheritance.